# Making Desktop 2 in Mountain Lion be shown in external display

Tags: macos, display, spaces

Is it possible to display Desktop 2 (Mountain Lion) in an external display?

The thing is I want to use Full Screen applications in an external display while using my Laptop display for non-full-screen applications.

With the Mirror Display unchecked, when I drag an application to the external display and set it to full screen, my laptop display goes black.

Comment: That also drives me crazy. And for apps that do not blacken the second screen, such as a YouTube video in Firefox at full scree, the cursor is hidden so I am unable to really use the apps running on the second screen. Sorry I do not have a fix.

Comment: It's ridiculous, but there's no real workaround if you use the 'official' full screen app mode as opposed to just maximising the windows. There's no avoiding the linen on all other displays. I don't think there's a way to bind a particular Space to a particular physical display either - it just treats the two displays as one large Space, separated only physically but not logically.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but perhaps [TotalSpaces](http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/totalspaces-how-virtual-desktops-on-os-x-got-its-groove-back) is worth a look.  $15, 14 day full-feature trial available as well.  http://totalspaces.binaryage.com/

Answer (score 1):

I have been using an external display for a little while and was confused about this to begin with.  I think it happens when you have a particular window on full screen.  That is to say that it is the extended display version of having a single window to the fore.  I started dragging windows to size manually and it stopped happening.